# Difficulty in understanding matplotlib axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

I've following data 
year
array([1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980,
       1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991,
       1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002,
       2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011])

physical_sciences
array([13.8, 14.9, 14.8, 16.5, 18.2, 19.1, 20. , 21.3, 22.5, 23.7, 24.6,
       25.7, 27.3, 27.6, 28. , 27.5, 28.4, 30.4, 29.7, 31.3, 31.6, 32.6,
       32.6, 33.6, 34.8, 35.9, 37.3, 38.3, 39.7, 40.2, 41. , 42.2, 41.1,
       41.7, 42.1, 41.6, 40.8, 40.7, 40.7, 40.7, 40.2, 40.1])

computer_science
array([13.6, 13.6, 14.9, 16.4, 18.9, 19.8, 23.9, 25.7, 28.1, 30.2, 32.5,
       34.8, 36.3, 37.1, 36.8, 35.7, 34.7, 32.4, 30.8, 29.9, 29.4, 28.7,
       28.2, 28.5, 28.5, 27.5, 27.1, 26.8, 27. , 28.1, 27.7, 27.6, 27. ,
       25.1, 22.2, 20.6, 18.6, 17.6, 17.8, 18.1, 17.6, 18.2])

When I run the following code

```
# Create plot axes for the first line plot
plt.axes([.05,.05,.425,.9])

# Plot in blue the % of degrees awarded to women in the Physical Sciences
plt.plot(year, physical_sciences, color='blue')

# Create plot axes for the second line plot
plt.axes([.525,.05,.425,.9])

# Plot in red the % of degrees awarded to women in Computer Science
plt.plot(year, computer_science, color='red')

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

[Graph generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61pFn.png)

My question is why the corrdinates specified by axes are not there on x-axis or is it work some other way. 
Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

From the [matplotlib documentation of `pyplot.axes`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axes.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axes) one can see that the argument to `axes` may be a

> 4-tuple of floats `rect = [left, bottom, width, height]`. A new axes is added with dimensions `rect` in normalized `(0, 1)` units using add_axes on the current figure.

This means that `plt.axes([.05,.05,.425,.9])` adds an axes with the lower left corner at `(.05,.05)` and with a width of `.425` and height of `.9`. Roughly speaking it spans the left part of the figure.

Mind that it is mostly not necessary to specify the positions of the axes at all. Just creating two subplots side by side is enough.

```
# Create plot axes for the first line plot
plt.subplot(121)

# Plot in blue the % of degrees awarded to women in the Physical Sciences
plt.plot(year, physical_sciences, color='blue')

# Create plot axes for the second line plot
plt.subplot(122)

# Plot in red the % of degrees awarded to women in Computer Science
plt.plot(year, computer_science, color='red')

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```